# Activity not opening after signing in

Tags: android, mobile

I'm currently creating an application that allows the user to login using a web api. While checking response of the API , i'm not getting any error.

```
{"error":0,"data":[{"id":"2","driver_name":"Test Driver","driver_lat":"","driver_long":"","driver_mobile_no":"9164618545","driver_password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","driver_token":"bef1032495ef4b2c891795fce1fa16c2","driver_image":"","is_active":"1","on_duty":"0","t_drivers":"0","created_at":"2017-07-04 06:38:22","last_activity_at":"2017-07-04 09:19:08"}],"msg":"Login Successfully."}
```

But while using the app, it does not go to the mainActivity. 
This is the login class:-

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button login1;
Session session;
private ConstraintLayout mRootLayout;
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
boolean status = false;

EditText mEdtEmail , mEdtPassword ;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mEdtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    mEdtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    session = new Session(login.this);

    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

   // sign_in();


    login1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String mobile = mEdtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mEdtPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            status = checkInternetConnection();

            if (status) {

                if (mobile.length() == 0) {
                    mEdtEmail.setError("Required");
                } else if (mobile.length() < 10) {
                    mEdtEmail.setError("Mobile no must be 10 char. long");
                } else if (password.length() == 0) {
                    mEdtPassword.setError("Required");
                } else {

                    new UserLoginTask(mobile, password, login.this).execute();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Snackbar.make(mRootLayout, "You don't have Internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String mUserName;
    private String mPassword;
    String msg ;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    Boolean loginStatus = false;
    private Activity activity;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    UserLoginTask(String userName, String password, Activity activity) {
        mUserName = userName;
        mPassword = password;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(login.this, "Loading. . .","Please Wait. . .", true);
        Toast.makeText(login.this,"toast 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            String result= WebService.postHttpResponse(mUserName, mPassword, activity);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
          //  Log.d("Json Array", "doInBackground: "+jsonObject);
           String status = jsonObject.optString("error");
         //   msg = jsonObject.optString("msg");
           // Toast.makeText(login.this,"toast 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(status.equals("0")){


                loginStatus = true ;


                session.setLogin(true);


                JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);

                status = jsonObject1.getString("msg");
                Log.e("DRIVER NAME -----" ,jsonObject1.getString("driver_name"));

                Driver driver = new Driver();

                driver.setId(jsonObject1.getString("id"));
                driver.setDriver_name(jsonObject1.getString("driver_name"));
                driver.setDriver_lat(jsonObject1.getString("driver_lat"));
                driver.setDriver_long(jsonObject1.getString("driver_long"));
                driver.setDriver_mobile_no(jsonObject1.getString("driver_mobile_no"));
                driver.setDriver_token(jsonObject1.getString("driver_token"));
                driver.setCreated_at(jsonObject1.getString("created_at"));
                driver.setLast_activity_at(jsonObject1.getString("last_activity_at"));

                sharedpreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences("MY" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  sharedpreferences.edit();

                editor.putString("driver_name",jsonObject1.getString("driver_name"));
                editor.putString("driver_mobile_no", jsonObject1.getString("driver_mobile_no"));
                editor.putString("id", jsonObject1.getString("id"));
                editor.putString("driver_token", jsonObject1.getString("driver_token"));
                editor.putString("driver_image", jsonObject1.getString("driver_image"));
                editor.putString("current_order_no", "");

                editor.commit();
                startActivity(intent);
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class).putExtra("driver_obj" , driver));

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                finish();

            }

            else {
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return msg ;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        super.onPostExecute(msg);

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(activity , msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
}

/*public void sign_in(){
    login1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    login1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this,"Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce){
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true ;
    Toast.makeText(this , "Please click BACK again to exit" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false ;
        }
    }, 2000);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    System.exit(0);*/

}

public boolean checkInternetConnection()
{

    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo[] inf = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (inf != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < inf.length; i++)
                if (inf[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Please Help!
Thanks!!

EDIT 1: Thanks a lot! I've gotten the solution for this. It was a really small error on my part!

Comment: You say: "it does not go to the mainActivity" what does it do? Can you share your mainActivity class please.

Comment: It just shows a blank toast message in the same activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are getting `JSONObject` in response from server.

This object contains three values:

1. `error`
2. `data`
3. `msg`

`error` contains error code in `integer` format.

`data` contains `JSONArray` which contain the details of the driver.

`msg` contains the message in `String` format.

So you need to write

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
int code = jsonObject.getString("error");
if (code == 0) {
    JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
    JSONObject data = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
    String msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");
    driver = new Driver();
    ...
}
```

and remove this from `doInBackground` method

```
Intent intent = new Intent("oodi_design.driver4.Activity.MainActivity");
startActivity(intent);
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class).putExtra("driver_obj" , driver));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
finish();
```

and write this code in `onPostExecute` method after displaying `Toast`

```
...
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class).putExtra("driver_obj" , driver));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
finish();
...
```

You need to declare `Driver` in `UserLoginTask` after `ProgressDialog` like

```
...
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Driver driver;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `jsonObject1.getString("msg");` don't have any `msg`

```
 {"error":0,"data":[{"id":"2",.....}],"msg":"Login Successfully."}

  // `                                ^^^^^  part of jsonObject`  
                     |_____________|
                            | first json object which has no msg key/value pair
                   |________________|
                            | jsonarray           
 |_______________________________________________________________|
                 |   
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
// response object
String status = jsonObject.optString("error");
// response json contains error , so far so good
..
..
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
// get the jsonarray
JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
// get first object

status = jsonObject1.getString("msg");
// there is no msg string in jsonObject1 hence error
```

so use

```
jsonObject.optString("msg");
```

**Note** : Apparently you are starting your `MainActivity` twice so remove one and from `doInBackground` which works on background thread so `don't do this`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("oodi_design.driver4.Activity.MainActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class).putExtra("driver_obj" , driver));
```

Start your activity from `onPostExecute`

Comment: Yes . Nice elaborate .

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh - Thanks!
But can you please elaborate?

Comment: we can't do the whole solution for you , you have to show your error/ exceptions details , plus i hope you read the `note` in answer and followed it

Answer (score 0):

From your attached `JSONObject`, its seems that `JSONObject` contains `two` string (`error` and `msg`) and one `JSONArray` named `data`.

**So you have to parse this JSON data as below:**

```
    .........
    ..............

    String result = WebService.postHttpResponse(mUserName, mPassword, activity);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    // ERROR & STATUS
    String status = jsonObject.optString("error");
    String msg = jsonObject.optString("msg");

    // DATA
    JSONArray jsonArrayData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

    // First DATA JSONObject
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArrayData.getJSONObject(0);

    ........
    ..............
```

**To start `MainActivity`, use below code in `onPostExecute()` :**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("driver_obj" , driver); // driver should be declared as global in `UserLoginTask` class.
    activity.startActivity(intent);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
    finish();
}
```

Hope this will help~